# Why my signers_seed is wrong?

Tags: spl-token

Do you know why I don't succeed to sign:

How the PDA is created:

```
    const [store] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [creator.publicKey.toBuffer(), new anchor.BN(country).toBuffer("le", 2)],
      program.programId,
    );
```

How the ATA for the PDA is created:

```
    const storeToken = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(provider.connection, creator, mint, store, true);
```

I don't succeed to sign on chain:

```
        invoke_signed(
            &transfer_to_buyer,
            &[...],
            &[&[
                &ctx.accounts.store.creator.to_bytes(),
                &ctx.accounts.store.country.to_le_bytes(),
            ]],
        )?;
```

The `signers_seed` are probably bad, do you know what I should put on `signers_seed` to sign ?

Comment: Please include how your `store` seeds are defined on-chain

Answer (score 2):

my mistake was that I was not adding the bump to the signers_seeds.

What works:

```
        invoke_signed(
            &transfer_to_buyer,
            &[...],
            &[&[
                &ctx.accounts.store.creator.as_ref(),
                &ctx.accounts.store.country.to_le_bytes().as_ref(),
                &[ctx.accounts.store.bump],
            ]],
        )?;
```